# Dynamically allocate contiguous locations in Masm x86

Tags: assembly, x86, dynamic-memory-allocation, masm

I am writing a compiler for a language of mine. In that, for expressions like

```
 a=b*(c+d)
```

,I have to store (c+d) in a variable. So far so good, but when I'm done with that expression, I want to destroy that variable and move on. Now, when I am allocating that variable I suddenly realize that to store the *address* of the variable I have created somewhere I need *yet another* variable. I find out that I need a pointer, but that pointer *itself* takes 1 dword. Nor does the HeapAllocate method allocate variables in contiguous spots so I can refer to them by,

```
 mov eax,[index0+i]
```

where i is the index of that variable, pretty much like an array.

So my question in short is:

How do I allocate memory in an array structure dynamically so that I can refer to them without using pointers and without remembering the address of each and every variable in the array?

Comment: Normally, you would not use the **heap** but the **stack** for such kinds of things.

Comment: ...and then, everything in the *stack frame* can be indexed with a single pointer.

Comment: First of all, I did not find a tutorial referring to memory alloc on stack. Can you refer me to one? And then, isnt the stack too small to hold large arrays as might possibly occur?

Comment: @debanshudas The stack vs heap question depends on the semantics of your language. For example, most C++ implementations use the stack for automatic storage vars and the heap for the dynamic storage. It's not mainly about the size. Anyway, people were telling you that you already have an array that can be accessed "without pointers": the stack. Either set up a framepointer or use fixed offsets from `e/rsp`. Probably the best "tutorial" is disassembling a few functions (with and without optimizations) from different compilers and looking at what they do.

Comment: The "tutorial" you should probably be reading is a text book on compiler construction.  Your not going to learn how to write a compiler from simple tutorials.